# ¿Quisiera saber cómo busco exactamente un valor en mi Lista_Enlazada en Python?

Tags: python, poo

Tengo:

```
class LES:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cabecera = None
        self.cola = None
        self.tamagno = 0

    def insertar(self, dato):

    def buscar(self, dato):
        for n in self.iterar():
            if dato == n:
                return True
        return False
```

```
Lista_Clinica=LES()
```

Ademas de tener mi clase clinica donde poseo un registro de Clinica.

```
class Clinica: #Clase para cada usuario
    def __init__(self,codigo,nombre,estado,direccion,fecha,ced):
        self.codigo_clinica = codigo
        self.nombre_clinica = nombre
        self.estado_clinica = estado
        self.direccion_clinica = direccion
        self.fecha_creacion = fecha
        self.cedula_dir = ced

    def registrar_clinica():
        os.system ("cls")
        #REGISTRAMOS NUEVO DIRECTOR PARA LA CLINICA
        print("\n=== REGISTRO DE CLINICA ===\n")
        contador = Lista_Clinica.tamagno + 1
        codigo = "CL%s" %contador
        print("Codigo: %s" %codigo)
        nombre = input("Nombre: ")
        estado = input("Estado de Ubicación: ")
        direccion = input("Direccion: ")
        fecha = obtenerFecha()
        ced = Director.registrar_director(fecha,codigo)   
        
        #Crea un objeto Clinica y envia ese objeto a la lista para su insercion
        Clinica_Nueva = Clinica(codigo, nombre, estado, direccion, fecha, ced)
        Lista_Clinica.insertar(Clinica_Nueva)
        print("\nLa Clinica '",nombre,"' (",codigo,") ha sido registrada.")
```

Al final del registro de la clinica. Yo envio todos estos parametros ingresados como un objeto (si no me equivoco) a la lista.

Lo que quiero es luego con el metodo `def buscar(self, dato):`
de mi `Lista_Clinica` si tengo alguna clinica registrada con XXXX código en especifico.

Ej: `Lista_Clinica.buscar("CL1")`

Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, pretendes que la función `buscar` reciba un código y busque en la lista de clínicas, la que tenga ese mismo código. Asumiendo que la función `iterar` devuelve un iterador de clínicas, es tan sencillo como:

```
def buscar(self, codigo):
    for n in self.iterar():
        if codigo == n.codigo_clinica:
            return True
    return False
```

En el caso de que el iterador devolviera algún tipo de nodo de la lista enlazada, sería algo como `codigo == n.valor.codigo_clinica`, siendo `n.valor` el atributo del nodo `n` que contiene el objeto clínica asociado a ese nodo de la lista enlazada.